# Hybrid apps fullScreen

Tags: css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I've fouded this plugin to get the Immersive Android view on a Hybrid app ([GitHub](https://github.com/mesmotronic/cordova-plugin-fullscreen))

But the navbar is attached into the StatusBar

[image]
i've tried with css ..

```
.platform-android.has-translucent-status-bar.app-header-bar{ padding-top:25px!important; }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely hide the status bar:

```
$ionicPlatform.showStatusBar(false);
```

Make sure to inject `$ionicPlatform` to the service/controller. Also make sure to install the Cordova Statusbar Plugin.

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar`

If you only want to push the content down a bit, you can do this:

```
body {
    padding-top: 25px !important;
}
```